# Problems using Git via Thunderbolt SSD (git can't recognize repository after reconnect)

Tags: macos, git, mount

I recently got an external thunderbolt-sata adapter and I'm running into some issues using git.  Since I'm a developer this is a HUGE HUGE HUGE problem for me! And since the thunderbolt technology is so new, these problems aren't well documented.

When i first git clone onto my thunderbolt, everything works fine.  But if i restart my computer, or swap out hard disks, git can no longer recognize the repo.

> `git status`
>
> fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

Not sure if this is directly related to how a drive is mounted with Thunderbolt or if this is just a problem people run into with git repo's on external drives in general.  But this issue has already cost me hours of productivity.  Imagine if you had to `git clone` every single time you wanted to work on a problem.  Imagine if you didn't know if you were losing important changes and couldn't even `git status`!

Also, i have set the GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM flag in `/etc/zshenv`

```
export GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM=1
```

So far, i've tried git cloning and diffing the .git folders, though i don't know if the original folder contains any diffs.  I'm imagining that something is labeled differently when the filesystem is remount, but i don't know what.  Here's the output of such a diff (the ccnx3 repo is recognized by git):

```
diff -rq CCNx-Federated-Wiki-Prototype/.git ccnx3/.git

Only in CCNx-Federated-Wiki-Prototype/.git: ._sourcetreeconfig
Only in CCNx-Federated-Wiki-Prototype/.git: COMMIT_EDITMSG
Only in CCNx-Federated-Wiki-Prototype/.git: FETCH_HEAD
Files CCNx-Federated-Wiki-Prototype/.git/HEAD and ccnx3/.git/HEAD differ
Only in CCNx-Federated-Wiki-Prototype/.git: MERGE_RR
Only in CCNx-Federated-Wiki-Prototype/.git: ORIG_HEAD
Files CCNx-Federated-Wiki-Prototype/.git/index and ccnx3/.git/index differ
Files CCNx-Federated-Wiki-Prototype/.git/logs/HEAD and ccnx3/.git/logs/HEAD differ
Only in CCNx-Federated-Wiki-Prototype/.git/logs/refs/heads: dc
Files CCNx-Federated-Wiki-Prototype/.git/logs/refs/heads/master and ccnx3/.git/logs/refs/heads/master differ
Files CCNx-Federated-Wiki-Prototype/.git/logs/refs/remotes/origin/HEAD and ccnx3/.git/logs/refs/remotes/origin/HEAD differ
Only in CCNx-Federated-Wiki-Prototype/.git/logs/refs/remotes/origin: master
Only in CCNx-Federated-Wiki-Prototype/.git/logs/refs: stash
Only in CCNx-Federated-Wiki-Prototype/.git/objects: 00
Only in CCNx-Federated-Wiki-Prototype/.git/objects: 0b
Only in CCNx-Federated-Wiki-Prototype/.git/objects: 21
Only in CCNx-Federated-Wiki-Prototype/.git/objects: 38
Only in CCNx-Federated-Wiki-Prototype/.git/objects: 3a
Only in CCNx-Federated-Wiki-Prototype/.git/objects: 42
Only in CCNx-Federated-Wiki-Prototype/.git/objects: 5c
Only in CCNx-Federated-Wiki-Prototype/.git/objects: 76
Only in CCNx-Federated-Wiki-Prototype/.git/objects: 9d
Only in CCNx-Federated-Wiki-Prototype/.git/objects: b2
Only in CCNx-Federated-Wiki-Prototype/.git/objects: b6
Only in CCNx-Federated-Wiki-Prototype/.git/objects: cc
Only in CCNx-Federated-Wiki-Prototype/.git/objects: d7
Only in CCNx-Federated-Wiki-Prototype/.git/objects: e5
Only in CCNx-Federated-Wiki-Prototype/.git/objects: fd
Only in ccnx3/.git/objects/pack: pack-4f050d825152b9fbe1b2d2c0e2a63d102fca151c.idx
Only in ccnx3/.git/objects/pack: pack-4f050d825152b9fbe1b2d2c0e2a63d102fca151c.pack
Only in CCNx-Federated-Wiki-Prototype/.git/objects/pack: pack-995c1e8dbf16bee47ff923bf210e0331f0242fa1.idx
Only in CCNx-Federated-Wiki-Prototype/.git/objects/pack: pack-995c1e8dbf16bee47ff923bf210e0331f0242fa1.pack
Files CCNx-Federated-Wiki-Prototype/.git/packed-refs and ccnx3/.git/packed-refs differ
Only in CCNx-Federated-Wiki-Prototype/.git/refs/heads: dc
Only in CCNx-Federated-Wiki-Prototype/.git/refs/remotes/origin: master
Only in CCNx-Federated-Wiki-Prototype/.git/refs: stash
Only in CCNx-Federated-Wiki-Prototype/.git: rr-cache
Only in CCNx-Federated-Wiki-Prototype/.git: sourcetreeconfig
```

Comment: Output of `cat .git/config`?

Comment: here's the output for the repo that's not working: [.git/config](https://gist.github.com/5615651)

Comment: Looks perfect, are you ejecting the disk properly each time instead of just yanking the cord out? Theres no reason Git would complain about you not having a valid repo if you have a `.git` folder and a valid `.git/config` file.

Comment: and that .git/config is identical to the one i just pulled down.

Comment: I keep all my Git projects in Dropbox and am able to clone a project on one computer and continue working on another, no problem. Have you considered using a cloud document service to store your projects?

Comment: let me see if dismounting properly is required.  maybe i'm corrupting it.  but i would never ever ever just yank the cord out.....

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30280/discussion-between-c00lryguy-and-dcunited001)